# VS 2015 can not connect to tfs

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

today when I want to connect to tfs from vs 2015, I saw this message:

> Could not load type
>   'Microsoft.TeamFundation.Client.KnownCapFlagsScc' From assembly 'Microsoft.TeamFundation.Client, Version=14.0.0.0,Culture=neture, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

it was happen but another Client with another user and workspace can work with the same collection and project.

Comment: I were checkin from Command Line but still this message ocure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 2days, finally, I can fix it but I can't figure out why it was happening.

Version of visual studio that I used, is 2015 u2, and tomorrow I update that to 2015 u3 and it was fix.

so that problem unclear but it was fix with a simple update!